# Can't open SSH public key

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to create a user and either displaying the contents with `debug` or adding the key to `authorized_keys`. But I keep getting the error that the file could not be located, while I've verified that it exists.

```
- name: Add gitlab user
  user:
    name: gitlab
    shell: /bin/bash
    comment: user for automated gitlab CI/CD
    generate_ssh_key: yes
  register: gitlab

- name: Add gitlab's pubkey to authorized_keys
  authorized_key:
    user: gitlab
    key: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/gitlab/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

Result:

```
TASK [Add gitlab's pubkey to authorized_keys] ***********************************************************************
[WARNING]: Unable to find '/home/gitlab/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)
fatal: [host]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'file'. Errorwas a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: could not locate file in lookup: /home/gitlab/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"}
```

What is causing this issue?

Note: `become: yes` is used globally and I've also tried `become: gitlab` for the authorized_key module

Comment: I suspect your problem is that `lookup(...)` runs on the local (control) host, not the remote (target) host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by @larsks, the issue is with the lookup function running locally instead of on the remote host.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you have confirmed the files exists, does the user running the playbook have access?  Normally the users 'gitlab'  and 'root' should be the only accounts allowed to read this file from the specified location.  If the playbook is not running as root or the gitlab user, that would explain why you are getting file not found